# AVPlayer seekToTime not correct With UISlider

Tags: ios, avplayer, uislider

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.slider.maximumValue = 30;
}

- (void)slide:(UISlider *)slider {
    NSLog(@"....progress  slider value:%d", (int)slider.value);
    CMTime showingTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((int)slider.value, 1);
    [self.player seekToTime:showingTime];
}
```

Everytime I slide the UISlider, The console log the right number as I slided. like 6 seconds. But the slider would jump back to 0; If I slide it to value bigger than 10, like 14, It would slide back to 10.

Can anybody help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

You gotta init a CMTime object based on UISlider's value at first. Then you call AVPlayer object's seek to time method. Pass the CMTime object as parameter.

```
CMTime showingTime = CMTimeMake(slider.value *1000, 1000);

[self.player seekToTime:showingTime toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift AVPlayer seek function**

Swift version

```
self.player.seek(
    to: CMTimeMake(
        value: Int64(playbackSlider.value * 1000),
        timescale: 1000
    ),
    toleranceBefore: .zero, 
    toleranceAfter: .zero
)
//can be read: Be at time
```

when you skip `toleranceBefore` and `toleranceAfter` - `.positiveInfinity` is used by default.

```
self.player.seek(
    to: CMTimeMake(
        value: Int64(playbackSlider.value * 1000),
        timescale: 1000
    )
)
//can be read: Be as you wish
```